Linking to a page that hasn't been added as a submenu leads to Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page
I'm creating a WordPress plugin that requires a couple of management pages. I have some pages that needs an ID to be passed into it such as a details page, and hence I have a list page that outputs the list of records and I have link to navigate to the details page passing in the record id.
The problem that I have is that I am receiving "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page." The only solution that seems to work is if I add the Details page to the submenu, however, that's pointless since the menu would be overcrowded and the pages wont work because the user would need to supply the id.
As a test case this is an example :
<?php
function homelab_test_list_page() {
    echo '<h2>List of Records</h2>';
    echo '<ul>';
    for ($id = 1; $id <= 10; $id++) {
        
        $url = add_query_arg(['page' => 'homelab_test_detail_page', 'id' => $id], admin_url('admin.php'));
        echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url($url) . '">This is record ' . $id . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

function homelab_test_detail_page() {
    // Check if the user has the capability to publish posts
    if (!current_user_can('edit_posts')) {
        wp_die(__('Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.'));
    }

    // Retrieve the ID from the query parameter and sanitize it
    $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? intval($_GET['id']) : 0;

    // Display the ID
    if ($id > 0) {
        echo '<h2>Detail Page</h2>';
        echo '<p>ID received: ' . $id . '</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>Invalid ID.</p>';
    }
}

I'm adding the list as :
//Test
add_submenu_page(
    'homelab', // Assuming this is a registered parent page
    'View Test List', // Page title
    'View Test List', // Menu title
    'edit_posts', // Capability
    'homelab_test_list', // Menu slug
    'homelab_test_list_page' // Function to display the page
); 

I've tried different methods including a custom page handler, but it hasn't worked and the only thing that has worked is if it is added to the submenu. Is there an alternate method to do this without having to add the details page to the submenu ?
